# Meaning of tf.keras.layers.LSTM parameters

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am having trouble understanding some of the parameters of `LSTM` layers in the `tf.keras.layers` API.

I am investigating using `CuDNNLSTM` layers instead of `LSTM` layers (to speed up training), but before I commit to `CuDNN` layers, I would like to have a full understanding of the parameters that I lose by using a `CuDNNLSTM` instead of a `LSTM` layer. I have read the docs, but they seem to assume some prior knowledge of `LSTM`s that I do not have.

I have listed the pararameters that `CuDNNLSTM` does not have (that `LSTM` has) and interspersed with my questions about them, respectively.

- `activation`
- `recurrent_activation`

  1. What is the difference between `activation` and `recurrent_activation`? I am assuming it has something to do with the activation for a cell vs. the activation for the full `LSTM` layer, but am unsure.
- `use_bias`

  2. If `use_bias` is True, where is this bias applied?
- `dropout`
- `recurrent_dropout`

  3. Again, what is the difference between `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout`? If `recurrent_dropout` is dropout between the LSTM cells, that does not make sense to me, because you would be ignoring the previous output, which I thought would defeat the purpose of having an RNN.
  4. Can either of these dropout parameters be substituted with a dropout layer before/after the LSTM layer (i.e. `tf.keras.models.sequential([Input(...), LSTM(...), Dropout(0.5)])` or `tf.keras.models.sequential([Input(...), Dropout(0.5), LSTM(...)])` instead of `tf.keras.models.sequential([Input(...), LSTM(..., dropout=0.5)])`)
- `implementation`

  5. I understand why this parameter is not in `CuDNN` layers, since it would probably make it harder to parallelize. However, in `LSTM`s, does this impact the result (i.e. with the same seed, will `implementation=1` converge to the same or different result as `implementation=2`)?
- `unroll`

I've read a lot about `LSTM`s, and am at a point where I've decided to start training things, otherwise I won't absorb much more hypothetical knowledge. I've tried a lot of things in modeling, too, but the network I'm training is really simple so nothing seems to impact the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `activation` vs `recurrent_activation`

If you look at the [LSTM equations](https://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/). `activation` (defaults to `sigmoid`) refers to the activations used for the gates (i.e. input/forget/output), and `recurrent_activation` (defaults to `tanh`) refers to the activation used for other things (e.g. the cell output h).

I can explain why the need to two intuitively. For a gate, a range between 0-1 sounds intuitive because a gate can be either on or off or in the middle, but not negative (thus `sigmoid`). However the cell output, will be more expressive and leads to less saturation as it ranges between -1 and 1 (thus `tanh`). It might also help with solving vanishing gradient. But I'm not entirely sure about that.

### `use_bias`

If `use_bias` is True, there will be a `+b` (e.g. `i_t = sigma(x_t Ui + h_t-1 Wi + bi)`) in the equations. If not there will be no bias (e.g. `i_t = sigma(x_t Ui + h_t-1 Wi)`). Personally, I always use a bias.

### `dropout` vs `recurrent_dropout`

The need for `dropout` and `recurrent_dropout` is that, applying dropout on time-dimension can be quite disasterious, as you are influencing the memory of the model. However applying `dropout` on input data, is pretty much what we do day to day with feed-forward models. So,

- `dropout`: Applies a dropout mask on the input data (`x`)
- `recurrent_dropout`: Applices a dropout mask on the previous state data (`h_t-1`)

### `implementation`

The implementation gives different ways to compute the same thing. The need for the differences might be the different memory requirements.

- `implementation=1`

  - Here, the computations are done as if you would have written the following equations. In other words, do those in four steps.

    - `i_t = sigma(x_t Ui + h_t-1 Wi + bi)`
    - `f_t = sigma(x_t Uf + h_t-1 Wf + bf)`
    - `o_t = sigma(x_t Uo + h_t-1 Wo + bo)`
    - `tilde{c}_t = tanh(x_c Uc + h_t-1 Wc + bc)`
- `implementation=anything else`

  - You do the above computations at one go as,

    - `z = x_t concat(Ui, Uf, Uo, Uc)`
    - `z += h_t-1 concat(Wi, Wf, Wo, Wc)`
    - `z += concat(bi, bf, bo, bc)`
    - apply activations

So the second implementation is much efficiant as there's only two matrix multiplications taking place.

### `unroll`

If true, it will unroll the RNN on the time dimension and do computations without a loop (which will be memory intensive). If false, this will be done with a `for` loop, which will take longer but less memory intensive.

The source code I referred is found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/e19c354920c3b246dda6598229210a582caaa1a9/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L2028). Hope this clarifies it.

Comment: Thanks @thushv89, this answers a lot! So from your comments, I assume that `dropout` can be substituted with a Dropout layer `tf.keras.models.Sequential([Input(...), Dropout(0.5), LSTM(...)])` because it is dropout on the input to the layer, but there is no substitute for `recurrent_dropout`. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is what I imagine.